# ¿Como poner un margin y border-bottom a un etiqueta <tr>?

Tags: html, css, css3, web

Trato de poner un `margin` y un `border-bottom` a la vez en una etiqueta `<tr>`  pero no me funciona, logre poner el borde de la siguiente manera:

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px 20px;
```

Pero al momento de quitar ese framento de `css` me sale el borde, obviamente sin el espacio que quiero. ¿De que forma puedo crear un margin entre `tr` y a la vez crear un `border` inferior?

```css
table{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 20px;
}

table tr{
    background-color: #00ff00;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #c10c0c;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

le dejo un ejemplo en `snippet` pero no le sale los bordes, es mejor q prueben localmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a [CSS section 17.6](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders) en el modelo de borde separado que es el que tu estás usando, las filas (tr) no pueden tener bordes.
Si quieres poder darle borde a los tr tienes que poner el código de la siguiente manera.

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px 20px;
}

table tr{
    background-color: #00ff00;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #c10c0c;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Como habrás notado hay un problema y es que no funciona el margen obviamente puesto que esta en modo collapse pero es que el collapse es necesario para poder darle borde a los tr.

Para poder tener el margen tienes que darle borde a los td, no te queda otra.

**CSS**

```
    table{
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0px 20px;
    }

    table td{
        background-color: #00ff00;
        border-bottom: 1pt solid #c10c0c;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Cualquier cosa</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```